# How to remove focus outlines in firefox 13

Tags: css, colors, accessibility, outline

This is going to smell like a duplicate but it isn't. I've tried this:

```
input:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

and it doesn't work in Firefox 13. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/mDQzG/1/

Firebug leaves me guessing what default is being applied here that I need to override. Just to be clear: I want to get rid of the blue outline completely.

P.S. Please do not hector me about accessibility. I'm doing this *for* accessibility. The design page that has a light blue background, and the browser default outline color doesn't visually appear against it.

Comment: I don't see any outline.... only the shadow you put on it.

Comment: You mean like: http://jsfiddle.net/mDQzG/3/

Comment: @Jared. Yep. Now I see it. Why on earth does jsfiddle add its own "system" styling? I'm sure they have their reasons, but, man... Write this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: "I'm doing this for accessibility", so what will you do to *enhance* accessibility then?

Comment: @Ryan. Well, I'm going to make the focus state visible using a combination of border and box-shadow. The default blue color focus color is literally invisible on my background, and my attempts at an bright orange `outline` is blended in a strange way that turns the outline to a deep mud color. There doesn't seem to be a way to control outline-opacity. There are a forest of minor rendering bugs here that I'm trying to navigate through. Any ideas on how to deal with this would be very welcome.

Comment: @Ben, Border will add space to the page. Outline lives on top of the page. I have a custom stylesheet on my home computer. I have used the chunk of code for ~5 years and never have experience a color blend. I will post it later tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer  [jsfiddle.net/mDQzG/3](http://jsfiddle.net/mDQzG/3)

Comment: You should write what was changed.

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```